# Admin, stuck with 999 products per page

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, catalog

This is kind of funny.

In `Admin > Products > Catalog` I set 2000 products per page (it now shows 999), however, the page never loads, apache2 is stuck with 100% CPU. The problem is that I cannot access this page any more.

One solution would be to change the value of products-per-page in database but I have no idea where this value could be.
Another solution would be to delete the products from database and re-import them, but I'll keep that as last-hope solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve it with the firefox developer tools.

Simply set `display: none` on the loading mask, restart apache2, set the "per-page" value to something lower and then reload the page

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to PHPMyAdmin
2. Select Database
3. Go to table `ui_bookmark`
4. Find user_id and go to `identifier` (column) -> default (value)
5. Copy default config and paste in to current config

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing similar issue in Chrome. I opened my backend in Firefox where it prompted a couple of times whether to stop the script or wait. I repeatedly clicked on wait, and finally all the 999 products loaded.

Then I reduced the Product listing from 999 to a lower number, say 20, and tried to access the backend from chrome & now all seems to be working fine.

Comment: This works with chrome as well :) Being patient seems like a reasonable solution, as the effort for this solution is minimal.